# Power BI Service invalid Snowflake credentials when using correct Snowflake credentials

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connection

I am having issues getting Power BI Service to accept my Snowflake credentials. I have created the report in Power BI Desktop with the same credentials, and it works just fine. Once I take that report and attempt to upload it to Power BI Service and input the credentials, it states that the credentials are invalid.

Here is the error code when trying to input my credentials. I have removed and replaced identifying information with placeholders within <>:

```
Unable to update connection credentials.
Invalid connection credentials.

Details:

The credentials provided for the Snowflake source are invalid. (Source at <accountidentifier>.snowflakecomputing.com;<warehouse>.)

Please have this information handy if you choose to create a support ticket.

Session Id: <Session Id>
RequestId: <RequestId>
Cluster URI: https://api.powerbi.com
Status code: 400
Time: Fri Jan 12 2024 08:44:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)Please have this information handy if  you choose to create a support ticket.

Session Id: <Session Id>
Cluster URI: https://api.powerbi.com
Time: Fri Jan 12 2024 08:44:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
```

- The account that I am using with Snowflake has the highest privilege available (Accountadmin), so I don't think this is the issue.
- I have tried this fix here https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/PowerBI-Service-displays-credentials-related-error-when-logging-in-or-publishing-report-from-PowerBI-Desktop which discusses assigning a default role to the Snowflake account you are using to log in. I have done this and given my account the default Public role. My account also defaults to the correct warehouse. Still no luck.
- As I said before above, these credentials work when used in the Power BI Desktop app.

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, if I missed something or need to include more information, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Have you checked if you are not in the case of this [article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Power-BI-Service-authentication-error-with-working-credentials)?